# Fig up error exec: "bundle": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: sinatra, docker, fig

I'm trying to run a Dockerized sinatra app with no database using fig, but I keep getting this error:

```
$ fig up
Recreating my_web_1...
Cannot start container 93f4a091bd6387bd28d8afb8636d2b14623a08d259fba383e8771fee811061a3:   exec: "bundle": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu-nginx

MAINTAINER Ben Bithacker ben@bithacker.org

COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock

WORKDIR /app

RUN ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c", "bundle install"]

ADD config/container/start-server.sh /usr/bin/start-server
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/start-server

ADD . /app

EXPOSE 9292

 CMD ["/usr/bin/start-server"]
```

The config/container/start-server.sh looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /app
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
bundle exec rackup config.ru
```

The fig.yml looks like this:

```
web:
 build: .
 command: bundle exec rackup config.ru
 volumes:
   - .:/app
 ports: 
    - "3000:3000"
  environment:
   - SOME_VAR=adsfasdfgasdfdfd
   - SOME_VAR2=ba2gezcjsdhwzhlz24zurg5ira
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple problems with this setup. Where is bundler installed? Normally you would `apt-get install ruby-bundler` and it would always be on your path.

I believe your immediate problem is that you're overriding the `CMD` from the `Dockerfile` with the `command` in the `fig.yml`.  I'm assuming (based on the contents of `start-server.sh`) that you need the path to be set? You should remove the `command` line from the `fig.yml`.

You're also overriding the `/app` directory in the container with the `volumes: .:/app` in the `fig.yml`. You probably also want to remove that line.